# Generic way of returning binary data without raw pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 3 classes like this (psuedocode):

```
class Parent {
    public:
        virtual void * getData(size_t & size) = 0;
};

class A : public Parent {
    public:
        void * getData(size_t & size) {
            size = sizeof(structA);
            structA * a = new structA();
            //fill er up
            return (void *) a;
        };
};

class B : public Parent {
    public:
        void * getData(size_t & size) {
            size = sizeof(structB);
            structB * b = new structB();
            //fill er up
            return (void *) b;
        };
};
```

`structA` and `structB` are POD C structs that I can't modify (provided by vendor) so I can't create a parent and return a polymorphic unique_ptr for example.

My question is: is there a way to have class A and B generically return their struct data without the use of raw pointers given the constraints I have?

Comment: Could you use a single function that returns a `std::variant` instead, or do you need to be able to add more types to the system dynamically?

Comment: All possible structs are known at compile time so I suppose a `std::variant` could work, I'll have to look into it. Although the cross-compiler GCC version only supports up to C++14, so I would probably have to use boost or something. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @juanchopanza One other idea I had was to have `structA` be a private class member and return a cast `void *` to it. It still returns a raw pointer, but in this case you don't have to worry about freeing it (though the tradeoff is you have to guaruntee `A` will not go out of scope before the pointer is used...)

Comment: variant has been there since c++11. Good luck with that.
You wont probably need this but you can copy the output in a vector of char; less efficient in your case but more flexible.

Comment: @Red.Wave do you have a link to the docs? I can only find the C++17 docs.

Comment: I think you can write a cleaner kludge starting with    `template Parent<STRUCT> : public STRUCT `

Comment: @RPGillespie. I checkef it up again. Variant was part of boost for quite a long time and finally part of std very recently. Standards are written for vendors and with difficult technicalities. The official & current version is not free of charge, but can be found at std isocpp websites. But as a very good and free programmers guide you may take a look at www.cppreference.com . It is not a tutorial, but a good reference to start with std.

Comment: "https://isocpp.org/std" is the Olympus of C++. You can ask the gods and they guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a smart pointer for the data, even if you don't put it in a polymorphic wrapper, eg:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    using dataPtr = std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>;
    virtual dataPtr getData(size_t & size) = 0;
};

class A : public Parent
{
public:
    dataPtr getData(size_t & size) override
    {
        size = sizeof(structA);
        dataPtr a(new structA, [](void *data){ delete static_cast<structA*>(data); });
        //fill er up
        return std::move(a);
    }
};

class B : public Parent
{
public:
    dataPtr getData(size_t & size) override
    {
        size = sizeof(structB);
        dataPtr b(new structB, [](void *data){ delete static_cast<structB*>(data); });
        //fill er up
        return std::move(b);
    }
};
```

Or:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    using dataPtr = std::shared_ptr<void>;
    virtual dataPtr getData(size_t & size) = 0;
};

class A : public Parent
{
public:
    dataPtr getData(size_t & size) override
    {
        size = sizeof(structA);
        dataPtr a(new structA, [](void *data){ delete static_cast<structA*>(data); });
        //fill er up
        return a;
    }
};

class B : public Parent
{
public:
    dataPtr getData(size_t & size) override
    {
        size = sizeof(structB);
        dataPtr b(new structB, [](void *data){ delete static_cast<structB*>(data); });
        //fill er up
        return b;
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Vee9DK)

Comment: Or `unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>`, which has less overhead than `std::function` one.

Comment: @Yakk: I was going to use `void(*)(void*)` originally, then decided to use `std::function` instead since it generally supports lambdas better. But, yes, a non-capturing lambda could be used with `void(*)(void*)`, too ([live demo](https://ideone.com/Vee9DK))